# Grouped aggregate utility (like SQL GROUP BY)?

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

Unix has several utilities for performing relational algebra-like operations on streams (`grep`, `join`, `cut`, additional things with `awk`).  Is there a grouped aggregate utility readily available (or installable on most Linux distros)?

The goal would be to take a file with some keys in one column and values in another, such as:

```
foo.txt   u1    394082
bar.txt   u2    3948
frob.c    u1    29322
```

And output a file that has the unique values of one column, along with some aggregate of the values in another column.  For example, the sum of the 3rd column by the 2nd:

```
$ aggregate --sum=3 --group-by=2 <data
u1 423404
u2 3948
```

Does such a utility exist (Perl, Awk, etc. one-liners don't count), or is it something waiting to be written?

Comment: You answered your own question. awk and/or perl are very useful for what you need. :)

Comment: Never used it, but from what I read about it here, [tag:r] sounds also an option.

Comment: Write an Awk, Perl or R one-liner.

Comment: Perl and awk one-liners don't count, but they solve the problem. On the other hand, `wc` and `grep -c`  count, but don't solve the problem. Use what doesn't count!

Answer (score 12):

I think I found this answer in another StackOverflow question, but I found "q" quite useful for that purpose: https://github.com/harelba/q.

E.g. your example goal would be achievable like that:

```
$ q "select c2, sum(c3) from data group by c2"
u1 423404
u2 3948
```

And since it uses sqlite as a backend you can use all sorts of sqlite functions to make calculations.

Comment: "q" is genius, many thanks for introducing

Answer (score 2):

With some constraints [GNU Recutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/recutils/) can do this.  First, it needs to be a CSV file, not TSV (Recutils doesn't seem to like TSV files), and needs a header.  But then I can do:

```
csv2rec foo.csv |recsel -G user -p 'user,sum(size)' |rec2csv
```

Not sure if this is better or worse than a Perl or Awk one-liner.

Comment: I'm discovering this tool and it's awesome. You can use grep/sed/awk/git on it. It's really a full database in a plain text with the advantage of being human-readible and unix-friendly, and the disadvantage that it's not SQL (with sqlite3 you would do a front-end for it, while with recutils you wouldn't). I love the idea of using vim and git for personal databases.

Answer (score 1):

If awk one-liners don't count, maybe you'll like the following shell (bash/ksh) one-liner:

```
sort -k2 data | ( while read c1 c2 c3; do if [ "$prev" = "$c2" ]; then
sum=$(expr $c3 + $sum); else if [ $prev ]; then echo $prev $sum; fi;
sum=$c3; prev=$c2; fi; done; echo $prev $sum)
```

Apart from `sort` and `expr` (for grouping and summing, respectively), the interesting ingredient used here is the read statement inside the while. And the parentheses, which create a subprocess, necessary for localizing the `$prev` and `$sum` variables.