# Group by and sum in shell script without awk

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, solaris, csv-simple

I have a file like:

```
$ cat input.csv
201,100
201,300
300,100
300,500
100,400
```

I want to add the values in column 2 which has same value in column 1. Expected output is as follows:

```
$ cat output.csv
201,400
300,600
100,400
```

I tried to do this by `awk` command but it is not working in Solaris. Please provide some alternative.

Comment: Please show us your awk code.

Comment: On Solaris, use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`, or add a `PATH=\`getconf PATH\`:$PATH` as the one in `/bin` is an ancient non-standard one.

Comment: The answers here focus on one-liners and custom scripts. For those looking for an existing utility, see this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85204/41737

Answer (score 6):

I think this'll do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$1]+=$2}END{ for (i in a) print i,a[i]}'
```

Comment: The title: "group by and sum in shell script **without awk**"

Comment: The answer is great, AWK rocks!!!

Comment: So use `uniq` or `sort`, but if OP explicitly ask for non-awk solution I believe that should be respected.

Comment: @jimmij I am curious on your `sh` answer. If you can achieve the above in `sh` only, I'll remove my answer!

Comment: @val0x00ff I've just submitted solution in pure bash. I don't want to criticize, I didn't downvote etc, just saying that OP asked to not use `awk`. Of course I agree that `awk` is the best tool for this job.

Comment: @jimmij Your answer is ofcourse the OP wanted. Thanks for providing this solution!

Answer (score 4):

Pure `bash`, one-liner:

```
unset x y sum; while IFS=, read x y; do ((sum[$x]+=y)); done <  input.csv; for i in ${!sum[@]}; do echo $i,${sum[$i]}; done
```

Or in more readable form:

```
unset x y sum
while IFS=, read x y; do
    ((sum[$x]+=y)); done < input.csv
for i in ${!sum[@]}; do
    echo $i,${sum[$i]}
done
```

The result:

```
100,400
201,400
300,600
```

Answer (score 1):

With `python` this can be done more effectively. This program by default expects the file to be named as 'file.txt', which you can change if needed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

col1, col2 = [ list(y) for y in zip(*[ x.strip().split(',') for x in open('file.txt').readlines() if x != '\n' ]) ]

for (offset,x) in enumerate(list(col1)):
    value = 0
    while col1.count(x) > 1:
        index = col1.index(x)
        col1.pop(index)
        value =  int(col2.pop(index))

        index = col1.index(x)
        col2[index] = int(col2[index]) + value

for x, y in zip(col1, col2):
    print(x,',',y)
```

Output:

```
201 , 400
300 , 600
100 , 400
```

Comment: Just use `sys.argv[1]` for a filename or read from `sys.stdin`, if filename is not specified.